# Android Sqlite update row wont work in Custom Dialog

Tags: java, android, sqlite, dialog

I've created a `class myDialog extends Dialog`
and in this class I create an instance of my `class DBHelper` that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`
In other activity insert, delete and update record work normally but in class myDialog only insert and delete work, update fails.
Why?
The only thing that changes between the call of the class activity to this dialog is:
in other activity like Main or Info

```
db = new DBHelper(this);
```

in class myDialog

```
DB1 = new DBHelper(getContext());
```

The logcat reporting this while call update in myDialog

`09-12 19:06:48.272: W/FileUtils(2444): Failed to chmod(/data/data/com.dan.client/databases/messaggi.db): libcore.io.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)`

I repeat and confirm that all other activity I also work out the update as one would expect.
Thank you in advance

Edit:The problem occurred after updating libraries Android in Eclipse. Before this update the problem did not present itself. Now it is known that in addition to show up in class Dialog occurs in other types of classes (AsyncTask, GcmListenerService ...) but NEVER in activity.
I tried to do an update of the DB with the same query that I use in the dialog before calling the dialog and the data is updated correctly.
In short, if an activity is not the update will not work, and the insert and select yes but no update, is that I use the update method passing a contentValues or execSQL direct.
The class DBHelper is so made:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 2;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbdata.db";
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE datiutente ("+
                "id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
                "mail   TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',"+
                "cel1   TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',"+
                "cel2   TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',"+
                "telfisso   TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',"+
                "indirizzo  TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',"+
                "paeseresidenza TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',"+
                "opzioni    TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000000000000000000',"+
                "nazionalita    TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'italiano',"+
                "nome TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',"+
                "cognome TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-');");     

}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    switch(newVersion) {
    case 2:

            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE datiutente ("+
                "id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
                "mail   TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',"+
                "cel1   TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',"+
                "cel2   TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',"+
                "telfisso   TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',"+
                "indirizzo  TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',"+
                "paeseresidenza TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',"+
                "opzioni    TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000000000000000000',"+
                "nazionalita    TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'italiano',"+
                "nome TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',"+
                "cognome TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',"+
                "sesso TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '-');"); //Add Field to test onUpgrade OK !!!!
            //db.close();
            break;
    default:
            throw new IllegalStateException(
            "onUpgrade() with unknown newVersion" + newVersion);
    }
}
public String[] RecuperaDatiUtente(){
    String[] datiu=new String[8];
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();//tryed this too
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from datiutente where id=1", null );
    if(res.getCount() > 0) {
        res.moveToFirst();
        datiu[0]=res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("nome"));
        datiu[1]=res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("cognome"));
        datiu[2]=res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("indirizzo"));
        datiu[3]=res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("mail"));
        datiu[4]=res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("cel1"));
        datiu[5]=res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("telfisso"));
        datiu[6]=res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("nazionalita"));
        datiu[7]=res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("paeseresidenza"));
    } else {
        datiu[0] = "default-209288";
    }
    res.close();
    //db.close();

    return datiu;

}
public boolean RegistraDatiUtente(String nome, String cognome, String indirizzo, String mail, String cel1, String telefono, 
        String nazione, String localita) {
    if (nome.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){nome="-";}
    if (cognome.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){cognome="-";}
    if (indirizzo.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){indirizzo="-";}
    if (mail.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){mail="-";}
    if (cel1.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){cel1="-";}
    if (telefono.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){telefono="-";}
    if (nazione.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){nazione="-";}
    if (localita.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){localita="-";}

    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from datiutente where id=1", null );
        if (res.getCount()>0) {
            res.close();
            db.close();
            db= null;
            SQLiteDatabase db2 = getWritableDatabase();

            //With update or execSql the problem is the same!
            /*ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put("nome", nome);
            contentValues.put("cognome", cognome);
            contentValues.put("indirizzo", indirizzo);  
            contentValues.put("mail", mail);
            contentValues.put("cel1" , cel1);
            contentValues.put("telfisso" , telefono);
            contentValues.put("nazionalita", nazione);
            contentValues.put("paeseresidenza", localita);
            db.update("datiutente", contentValues, "id = 1",null);*/
            String sql = "update datiutente set nome='"+nome+"'," +
                    "cognome='"+cognome+"',"+
                    "indirizzo='"+indirizzo+"',"+
                    "mail='"+mail+"',"+
                    "cel1='"+cel1+"',"+
                    "telfisso='"+telefono+"',"+
                    "nazionalita='"+nazione+"',"+
                    "paeseresidenza='"+localita+"' where id=1";
            db2.execSQL(sql);
        } else {
            res.close();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put("nome", nome);
            contentValues.put("cognome", cognome);//id inserzione
            contentValues.put("indirizzo", indirizzo);  
            contentValues.put("mail", mail);
            contentValues.put("cel1" , cel1);
            contentValues.put("telfisso" , telefono);
            contentValues.put("nazionalita", nazione);
            contentValues.put("paeseresidenza", localita);
            SQLiteDatabase db3 = getWritableDatabase();             
            db3.insert("datiutente", null, contentValues);              
        }

        //db.close();
        return true;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return false;
    }               
}
```

In myDialog I do so:

```
public class DialogFormReg extends Dialog {
private DBHelper DB1;//try public too
public DialogFormReg(Context context) {//, boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener cancelListener
    super(context);//, cancelable, cancelListener
    //this.context = context; try it, don't work
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.registrazione_layout);
    DB1 = new DBHelper(getContext()); 
    String[] datiut= DB1.RecuperaDatiUtente();
}
    btConfRegistra.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            cel1 = edtCell1.getText().toString();
            mail = edtMail.getText().toString();
            indi = edtIndirizzo.getText().toString();
            nome = edtNome.getText().toString();
            cog = edtCognome.getText().toString();
            naz = edtNazione.getText().toString();
            loc = edtLocalita.getText().toString();
            telefono = edtTelefono.getText().toString();

            String[] datiu= DB1.RecuperaDatiUtente();
            boolean reg = false;    

            if (!datiu[0].equalsIgnoreCase("default-209288")) {     
                //This only works if the instance is created in the DBHelper Activity
                reg = DB1.RegistraDatiUtente(datiu[0], datiu[1], datiu[2], datiu[3], datiu[4], datiu[5], datiu[6], datiu[7]);
                if (reg) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Dati Aggiornati", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dismiss();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Errore in aggiornamento dati, ripetere", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                //This always works well
                reg= DB1.RegistraDatiUtente(nome, cog, indi, mail, cel1, telefono, naz, loc);
                if (reg) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Dati Registrati", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dismiss();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Errore in registrazione dati, ripetere", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }                   
            }
        }
    });

}
```

This is my 2nd day of work on this problem, I am a little worried.
After all, the Dialog class is the last one that worries me, now I worry a lot more other (AsyncTask and GcmListener first of all) who no longer work as before were fine. I shot in the knee?

I am sure that resolving the Dialog will work in all the other classes Activity why not post other code.

This is my code where call Dialog, it's in the Main.class activity

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
   if (id == R.id.item4) {
       //tryed "this" - "getApplicationContext()" - "getContext()"
       DialogFormReg DLG = new DialogFormReg(this);
       DLG.show();      
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

LOG CAT - LAUNCH APP CALL DIALOG AND UPDATE

```
    09-14 09:19:55.585: D/dalvikvm(17135): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 68K, 5% free 3098K/3232K, paused 189ms, total 192ms
    09-14 09:19:55.585: I/dalvikvm-heap(17135): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.693MB for 635812-byte allocation
    09-14 09:19:55.675: D/dalvikvm(17135): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 4% free 3716K/3856K, paused 80ms, total 80ms
    09-14 09:19:56.125: W/FileUtils(17135): Failed to chmod(/data/data/com.dan.client/databases/messaggi.db): libcore.io.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
    09-14 09:19:56.155: I/dalvikvm(17135): Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
    09-14 09:19:56.165: W/dalvikvm(17135): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 246: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
    09-14 09:19:56.175: D/dalvikvm(17135): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00c2
    09-14 09:19:56.195: I/dalvikvm(17135): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzh
    09-14 09:19:56.195: W/dalvikvm(17135): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 549: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
    09-14 09:19:56.205: D/dalvikvm(17135): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
    09-14 09:19:57.265: D/com.facebook.AppEventsLogger(17135): Got unexpected exception: java.io.EOFException
    09-14 09:19:57.325: D/dalvikvm(17135): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 315K, 9% free 3913K/4292K, paused 54ms, total 57ms
    09-14 09:19:57.385: I/RegistrationIntentService(17135): Prima di db helper
    09-14 09:19:57.635: E/ActivityThread(17135): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
    09-14 09:19:57.685: W/FileUtils(17135): Failed to chmod(/data/data/com.dan.client/databases/messaggi.db): libcore.io.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
    09-14 09:19:57.725: D/Facebook-publish(17135): FacebookException: No attribution id available to send to server.
    09-14 09:19:58.205: D/(17135): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb83282d0, tid 17135
    09-14 09:19:58.455: W/EGL_emulation(17135): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    09-14 09:19:58.525: D/OpenGLRenderer(17135): Enabling debug mode 0
    09-14 09:19:59.185: I/Choreographer(17135): Skipped 92 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    09-14 09:20:05.145: E/ActivityThread(17135): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
    09-14 09:20:07.125: D/dalvikvm(17135): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 285K, 8% free 4139K/4488K, paused 53ms, total 64ms
    09-14 09:20:12.335: D/dalvikvm(17135): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 488K, 12% free 4162K/4716K, paused 48ms, total 55ms
    09-14 09:20:12.335: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(17135): A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.dan.client/databases/messaggi.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
After call Dialog
    09-14 09:25:30.825: W/EGL_emulation(17135): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    09-14 09:25:30.955: I/Choreographer(17135): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    09-14 09:25:33.555: D/dalvikvm(17135): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 271K, 11% free 4233K/4716K, paused 47ms, total 51ms
    09-14 09:25:33.785: W/ResourceType(17135): Skipping entry 0x7f0b0032 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
    09-14 09:25:33.795: W/ResourceType(17135): Skipping entry 0x7f0b0032 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
    09-14 09:25:33.795: W/ResourceType(17135): Skipping entry 0x7f0b0032 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
    09-14 09:25:33.805: W/ResourceType(17135): Skipping entry 0x7f0b0032 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
    09-14 09:25:33.805: W/ResourceType(17135): Skipping entry 0x7f0b0032 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
    09-14 09:25:33.805: W/ResourceType(17135): Skipping entry 0x7f0b0032 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
    09-14 09:25:33.935: W/FileUtils(17135): Failed to chmod(/data/data/com.dan.client/databases/messaggi.db): libcore.io.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
    09-14 09:25:33.965: I/DialogFormReg(17135): OnCreate
    09-14 09:25:34.035: I/Choreographer(17135): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    09-14 09:25:34.875: W/EGL_emulation(17135): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    09-14 09:25:35.125: I/Choreographer(17135): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    09-14 09:25:42.585: W/EGL_emulation(17135): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    09-14 09:25:44.995: D/dalvikvm(17135): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 231K, 7% free 4513K/4808K, paused 45ms, total 46ms
Nothing error appeare after call update
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said your code works well in activity than pass the Context of activity to your Dialog class using your Dialog class constructor. and use it as

```
public class DialogFormReg extends Dialog {
private DBHelper DB1;//try public too
private Context ctx;
public DialogFormReg(Context context) {//, boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener cancelListener
    super(context);//, cancelable, cancelListener
    ctx = context; //try it, don't work
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.registrazione_layout);
    DB1 = new DBHelper(ctx); 
    String[] datiut= DB1.RecuperaDatiUtente();
}
    btConfRegistra.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            cel1 = edtCell1.getText().toString();
            mail = edtMail.getText().toString();
            indi = edtIndirizzo.getText().toString();
            nome = edtNome.getText().toString();
            cog = edtCognome.getText().toString();
            naz = edtNazione.getText().toString();
            loc = edtLocalita.getText().toString();
            telefono = edtTelefono.getText().toString();

            String[] datiu= DB1.RecuperaDatiUtente();
            boolean reg = false;    

            Log.e("size",""+datiu.length);

            if (!datiu[0].equalsIgnoreCase("default-209288")) {     
                //This only works if the instance is created in the DBHelper Activity
                reg = DB1.RegistraDatiUtente(datiu[0], datiu[1], datiu[2], datiu[3], datiu[4], datiu[5], datiu[6], datiu[7]);
                if (reg) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Dati Aggiornati", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dismiss();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Errore in aggiornamento dati, ripetere", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                //This always works well
                reg= DB1.RegistraDatiUtente(nome, cog, indi, mail, cel1, telefono, naz, loc);
                if (reg) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Dati Registrati", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dismiss();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Errore in registrazione dati, ripetere", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }                   
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Yes this is the problem.

Comment: The problem is not solved, I not understanding your answer, sorry.

Comment: try to call it as
`DialogFormReg DLG = new DialogFormReg(YourActivity.this);`

Comment: did you added constructor in your dialog class

Comment: also paste the full log cat here

Comment: Ok added costructor Dialog class and the log cat.

Comment: your database object is leaked... you are not closing it after opening it in your database class methods. and use asyncTask for database operations.. you are getting warning of Operations on main thread.

Comment: remove the comment mark on `db.close()` in  `public String[] RecuperaDatiUtente()` method

Comment: and in `RegistraDatiUtente()` close `db2` and `db3` respectively after the operations.

Comment: Sorry but the AsincTask implementation is in DBHelper or in myDialog class?

Comment: Only with db close method nothing are changed, problem persist.

Comment: Yes! I'm trying to write methods AsyncTask and it looks like the update method now functions but continuously but still receive EPERM error on the database after the execution of the method.

Comment: did you try my edited code?? and see the size in logcat.

Comment: Size of array is 8, this works. But with AsycTask update working but I receive always the EPERM error.

Comment: is it working or not accept this exception? Is it crashing your app??

Comment: The application does not crash, the data is updated in the database but in the logcat still read 09-14 11: 26: 08545: W / FileUtils (13270): Failed to chmod (/data/data/com.dan.client/databases /messaggi.db): libcore.io.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted). See you later, I go to eating!

Comment: you can search google for the exception `libcore.io.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted).` , i did but no solution, so i suggest you to move forward... if every thing is working accept this..

Comment: I want to thank you for the invaluable help they have given me. I tried very well on the type of error, but I have not found even what it refers to the code 776.
Gladly I accept your solution and, as you say, go ahead.

Comment: hmm... pleasure to help... bro :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simulate your problem and update worked for me. He is my snippet.

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog {

    public MyDialog(Context context) {
       super(context);
    }

    public void showDialog(){
       this.setContentView(R.layout.mydailoglayout);
       DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(getContext());
       dbHelper.updateContact("Tto","Trial");
       dbHelper.getData("Trial");
    }
}
```

I think there is problem with update query it is not because of custom dialog.

Comment: The problem is presente in another class (not Activity class) too.